# Hashing using chaining

Tags: time-complexity, data-structures, hashing

In resolving collisions while hashing by chaining , if we store keys in the list in sorted manner, will we obtain any substantial performance in successful searches , insertion, deletion? What would be the time - complexities of these operations if we maintain sorted lists in chaining?(assume keys are integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no asymptotic speedup.  Searching a sorted list requires examining $n/2$ items on average and $n$ items in the worst case (where $n$ is the length of the list), searching an unsorted list requires examining $n/2$ items on average if the item is in the list and $n$ items in the worst case, so the worst-case asymptotic running time is $O(n)$ either way.

Inserting into a sorted list takes $O(n)$ time, while inserting into an unsorted list can be done in $O(1)$ time if you use an appropriate data structure (e.g., a linked list).